# go get cannot fetch package in china mainland

Tags: go

I wanna download the golang.org/x/text package, and configure GOPROXY. But when I try to fetch it by go get, it return a error.

```
PS D:\workspace_for_go\learn_go\src\encoding> go get -u golang.org/x/text
unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/text": https fetch: Get "https://golang.org/x/text?go-get=1": dial tcp 216.239.37.1:443: connectex: A connection
 attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host ha
s failed to respond.
```

here is my go env shows

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> go env
set GO111MODULE=off
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\82341\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\82341\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\82341\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct
set GOROOT=D:\golang
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=D:\golang\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\82341\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build655234154=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

is the GOPROXY only effect in the moudle aware mode not GOPATH mode ?

Answer (score 2):

From the output it cannot connect to the https://proxy.golang.org which is blocked.

```
$ go get github.com/joho/godotenv
go get: module github.com/joho/godotenv: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/joho/godotenv/@v/list": dial tcp 142.251.42.241:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

You can set the proxy with `go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn`

```
$ go get -v github.com/joho/godotenv
go: downloading github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
github.com/joho/godotenv
go get: added github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
```

Comment: restart of vscode is required after executing the command "go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn"